# How to make windows 10 bootable usb under Ubuntu when even mkusb didn't help?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, mkusb

I tried from the command line, i tried mkusb, since i read windows 10 can't be made the old way, but it still doesn't boot it.

I'm with Ubuntu 17.04, want to make windows 10 bootable USB to boot it on a macbookpro that is with grub and old ubuntu.

I want to wipe the whole hdd, since ill be repurposing it for someone else.

Comment: MKUSB works, just tried it myself a few days ago. Perhaps you should check if your ISO has been correctly downloaded first.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: *i tried mkusb* implies you already tried but now you're asking how? So, you probably didn't follow the correct instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: You can check that the file is good using `mdsum filename.iso` where `filename.iso` is replaced by the actual filename of the Windows iso file. You need an uploaded value of what the answer should be (to compare with the result of your command). If you cannot find an uploaded value, you can download twice and check that the md5sums are the same for both versions of the iso file.

Comment: It is also worth testing in another computer (a PC), if your USB pendrive is bootable. The problem might be that you have not been able to make your MacBook Pro understand, that it should boot from the USB pendrive.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the image is intact by running a checksum. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/662162/microsoft-windows-iso-checksums) describes how you can get a checksum from Microsoft. (I can't confirm that's how to find it, since I don't have an MSDN account.) You'll want to run `sha1sum path/to/image.iso` and compare the result to Microsoft's checksum. "`path/to/image.iso`" should be replaced with the location/name of your image. If they provide something like and MD5 or SHA256 checksum, then you'd run `md5sum` or `sha256sum`.

If you think mkusb may not be working, you could just flash the image directly using `dd`. The command would be `sudo dd bs=4M if=path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdx`, where `/dev/sdx` is the USB device you want to copy to. You can find that by unplugging the USB drive, running `lsblk`, pluggin the USB in, and running `lsblk` again. The device that shows up in the second output of `lsblk` but not the first is your USB device. (It's also worth comparing the drive size and name. `lsblk` should tell you the size by default and the name if it's mounted.) Please note that you should *really* try to use a higher-level tool like mkusb or unetbootin first. From what I understand, `dd` copies byte-for-byte, ignoring partition headers. Whatever device you specify in the `of=` argument will become Windows, *even if that's the drive your OS is on*.

Since you're installing on a Macbook, it would also be worth checking that this image *can* be installed on there and that it's able to live-boot.

Sorry, I don't have the rep to comment directly. (Seems so backwards...)

Comment: `dd` doesn't work for newer Windows 10 ISOs. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive > Quoting: *t was not possible to extract the content from the Windows iso file directly to a USB pendrive. The files were not copied correctly (with any of the standard copying tools: cp, rsync, **dd**) in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS*

Comment: @JoeShields, Maybe you have enough rep to comment now. You can try (and remove it, if only a test, but let it remain, if you think the comment is useful to solve the problem of the original question).